# Adding a time string HH:MM (hours and minutes) to date timestamp

Tags: php, string, timestamp

I need to add a time stored in strong (format: hh:mm) to a date timestamp which before have no hours information (e.g. 2018-06-12 00:00:00). How to do it?

I would like to do this:

```
$startTime = "11:45";
$startDate = 1528754400; // 2018-06-12 00:00:00

$startDate = $startDate + $startTime; //2018-06-12 11:45:00
```

Comment: Have a look at and use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php). The given [examples](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.examples-arithmetic.php) should guide you to do what you want!

Comment: Did the answer resolve your question?

Comment: Yup. I've actually used my solution. Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just came across with this using `strtotime`:

```
$startTime = "11:45";
$startDate = 1528754400; // 2018-06-12 00:00:00
$startTimeTmp = explode(":",$startTime);

$finalTimestamp = strtotime("+".$startTimeTmp[0]." hours ".$startTimeTmp[1]." minutes", $startDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do some simple math and get there. Multiple minutes by 60 and hours by 3600 and you'll get the number of seconds the hours/minutes take up.

```
$startTime = "11:45";
$startDate = 1528754400;
$time = explode(':', $startTime);
$minutes = $time[1] * 60;
$hours = $time[0] * 3600;
```

Then just piece it back together. (the timestamp is the number of seconds since 1970 so just adding to it should be fine)

```
$startDate + $minutes + $hours
```

https://3v4l.org/U2jHL

An alternative approach would be using the datetime class.

```
$startTime = "11:45";
list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $startTime);
$date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', 1528754400));
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $hours .'H' . $minutes . 'M'));
```

https://3v4l.org/D51XB

Comment: I'd strongly not recommend working with dates/times on a string basis.

Comment: @Jeff I've added a datetime approach but it is still being based on a string approach. `$startTime` can't just be passed in because the function won't know if it is hours/minutes, or minutes/seconds, right, or is there a way to define the structure of the string?

Comment: Yes, you're right, we somehow have to get the hours and minutes out of that string.